# How to escape indicator characters (colon and hyphen) in YAML

Tags: escaping, yaml, delimiter

In a config file, I have a key to which I wish to assign a URL. The problem is that YAML interprets `:` and `-` characters as either creating mappings or lists, so it has a problem with the line

```
url: http://www.some-site.example/
```

(both because of the colon following HTTP and the hyphen in the middle)

Is there an explicit way to escape `:` and `-`? Or would it work to just put the whole thing in single quotes and call it a day?

Comment: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Quotes:

```
"url: http://www.some-site.example/"
```

To clarify, I meant “quote the value” and originally thought the entire thing was the value. If `http://www.some-site.example/` is the value, just quote it like so:

```
url: "http://www.some-site.example/"
```

Comment: It depends on the parser, apparently. This didn't work with Jekyll YAML.

Comment: YAMLDotNet also renders quotes.

Comment: Nothing better? Because then quotes need to be escaped themselves, which does not solve the problem but simply moves it forward ...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger: Is there something wrong with escaping quotes?

Comment: Well, it would be much cooler to have an error-proof document, just like markdown, so the non-tech guys of the team can edit it (Eg. locale files in Rails) without any risk of breaking it!

Comment: Relevant link about the significance of quotes https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/1175496 -- along with that question's OP linking to YAML cookbooks for more reference http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#double-quoted_strings

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the line isn't a key-value pair but rather a list entry. For `- PS4="+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }"`, Travis complains about the colon at `${FUNCNAME[0]}():` (the same with single quotes).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: The quotes go around the entire string. `- 'PS4="+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }"'`

Answer (score 309):

What also works and is even nicer for long, multiline texts, is putting your text indented on the next line, after a pipe or greater-than sign:

```
text: >
    Op dit plein stond het hoofdkantoor van de NIROM: Nederlands Indische 
    Radio Omroep
```

A pipe preserves newlines, a gt-sign turns all the following lines into one long string.

Comment: ...and a newline is added at the end, which is usually not what you want.

Comment: @equaeghe: You can use `>-` or `|-` in order to prevent this.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution. Completely avoids having to escape other characters in your text. +++90000 points

Comment: is it possible to have a list of multilines somehow? I've tried `- >` but the items after the first are ignored.

Comment: @ffghfgh - I had a list item with a colon in it and worked around it like this:

`- |  
       This is some text: with a colon in it!`

Comment: @ffghfgh - urg! I can't figure out how to format the code properly in the comment and now I can't edit the original comment.

Basically, I used a list item with a pipe, like this: `- |` and then on a new line I indented the list item text so that the first character lined up with the pipe.

I hope that helps, it worked for me in a Rails 4.2 locale file.

Comment: That works for Ansible too, when using 'when' clause and comparing a var to a string that contains a double colon.

Answer (score 114):

According to the YAML spec, neither the `:` nor the `-` should be a problem. `:` is only a key separator with a space after it, and `-` is only an array indicator at the start of a line with a space after it.

But if your YAML implementation has a problem with it, you potentially have lots of options:

```
- url: 'http://www.some-site.example/'
- url: "http://www.some-site.example/"
- url:
    http://www.some-site.example/
- url: >-
    http://www.some-site.example/
- url: |-
    http://www.some-site.example/
```

There is explicitly no form of escaping possible in "[plain style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859)", however.

Comment: The linter of travisCI complains about colons in unusual - http://lint.travis-ci.org/

Comment: For Travis CI, it seems colons inside single quotes are OK.

Comment: Be caution when pasting a json in a yaml file. It's quite common to naively add a space after `:`.

Comment: Agreed. You should not have to quote it. If you do, the library has a bug.

Comment: I used a JSON string in my YAML file and I could just delete the space after the : which fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 37):

Quotes, but I prefer them on the just the value:

```json
url: "http://www.some-site.example/"
```

Putting them across the whole line looks like it might cause problems.

Answer (score 25):

Another way that works with the YAML parser used in Jekyll:

```
title: My Life&#58; A Memoir
```

Colons not followed by spaces don't seem to bother Jekyll's YAML parser, on the other hand. Neither do dashes.

Comment: … are character entities part of YAML? And is what Jekyll uses actually YAML?

Comment: Jekyll claims to use it: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/ I can't find anything about character entities in the YAML spec, so I suspect Jekyll is aberrant, but I think this answer serves well for people Googling "yaml escape colon" like me ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I came here trying to get my Azure DevOps Command Line task working. The thing that worked for me was using the pipe (`|`) character. Using `>` did not work.

Example:

```
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo "Selecting Mono version..."
      /bin/bash -c "sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_18_1"
      echo "Selecting Xcode version..."
      /bin/bash -c "echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MD_APPLE_SDK_ROOT;]'/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app;sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Comment: I used same thing in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but until I needed pipe '|' in script - it fails silently on it :(

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with the question. The question is about colons and dashes in YAML. This looks like a solution to an entirely different problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't agree that this is related to an entirely different problem. The answer adds additional information about a specific use case and based on the upvotes it has helped some people. When I Google for something and a related question shows up in the results, I find it very useful to share my solution so that when others search for the same thing, they can find the solution as well.

Comment: You need the pipe, because the pipe preserves newlines within the block while ">" converts the whole block into a single line.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `@ConfigurationProperties` with Spring Boot 2 to inject maps with keys that contain colons then you need an additional level of escaping using square brackets inside the quotes because spring only allows alphanumeric and '-' characters, stripping out the rest. Your new key would look like this:

```
"[8.11.32.120:8000]": GoogleMapsKeyforThisDomain
```

See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11386) github issue for reference.

Comment: This is the most helpful in my current use case. Thanks

Comment: Also helped in my case

Answer (score 6):

GitHub actions complain about

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}"  https://example.com/try.txt
```

but it's fine when there is no space after colon, like

```
curl -L -H "Authorization:token ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}"  https://example.com/try.txt
```

Comment: Use multi-line commands, either by starting with > or | and then write you command on the next line.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with the question.  The question is about colons in YAML.  This looks like a solution to an entirely different problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  To be clear this is *exactly* the problem that brought me here.  A .gitlab-ci.yml file that has a curl command of the syntax above where a header needs to be added, and YAML pukes on the colon followed by a space, clearly shown above.  In this case curl works without the space, so it is a legit way to solve the problem, as are all the others.

Comment: Should probably include whether Github actions is using YAML and if not, would it be compatible with your solution?