# How to set authorization in mongodb config file?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, configuration-files

I run `mongod.exe` in server with this option in `cmd.exe`:

```
mongod.exe --dbpath=path --auth
```

And now, how can I do this in a config file?
my `mongod.cfg`:

```
dbpath=D:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data

security=
authorization= enabled
```

I get this error :

> Error parsing INI config file: unknown option security.

Comment: [Configuration File Options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

Comment: i read this and use YAML . but get alot of error . i think that is for unix base system not windows

Comment: its work.
`dbpath=D:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data
auth=true`

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### For mongod **version 2.4** (ini config file)

```
auth = true
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#auth

### For mongod **versions 2.6+** (yaml config file)

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization
https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization

Comment: I have the problem on v3.2.18. Where `--auth` works.. but `security:authorization: enabled` done not, giving UserNotFound. Any thoughts?

Comment: @codesmarter, are you sure your config file is being used?  e.g. You have the `-f` or `--config` option specified when starting mongod, or have the config file in the correct location if using a system default install?  You also could check that you are authenticating against the correct database and that the database has the users you expect (e.g. check output of `db.getUsers()`).

Comment: Thanks, You are right that the config was reading from a different database.

Comment: As stated in other answers the right config was wrapping with quotes `"enabled"`

Comment: @CarloRodríguez, being YAML, the quotes should not matter is this case.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml

Answer (score 32):

mongodb version 3.2

this is the correct config

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

with quotes since the value is a string as per the documentation

Comment: correct way to do it in 3.2, set this value in mongo.cfg.

Comment: But this is still not working on my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973998/mongodb-authentication-not-enabled-on-linux-server

Answer (score 11):

```
security:
   authorization: "enabled"
```

This is correct as stated above, one thing to note is if it still doesn't work make sure you didn't use a tab for the authorization line it won't work you need to just use spaces.

Comment: that's right, but you have to check log telling what you are dealing with error in YAML(Error parsing YAML). And one more thing - 2 spaces from the start of the string authorization, if none then error in yaml

Answer (score 8):

Just needs to say

```
auth=true
```

You don't need any of the other options!

Comment: I changed the config file and put your configuration `auth=true` and when I execute `mongo` I got a free access. Do I need to do any other configuration?

Comment: can you share the mongod.cfg fully after that update?

Answer (score 6):

If you are use YAML

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

working for 2.6 or high.

But if you don't use YAML.

```
auth: true
```

I'm use mongodb v3.0.2, v3.6.5, v4.0.3, both files are working correctly.

INI CONFIG

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017

journal=true
auth = true
```

YAML CONFIG

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 0):

On DigitalOcean you get the 3.6.3 version but with 2.* style config files. Which makes it confusion when reading all the comments above.

So, instead of following the DigitalOcean Guide of installing MongoDB ([this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04)), you'd better take the official MongoDB Guide ([this one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/))

Answer (score 0):

Really late to they party.

For me nothing of the above worked (on windows, on Linux "authorization: enabled" works fine as long as permissions are right). 
Ended up creating a service of my own with --dbpath and --auth options using a third party service manager. Works like a charm.

I perfectly aware that this is not a direct answer but I hope, this will help someone.

Side note though, I could not use "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\4.2\Server\data" folder. No write permissions.

Comment: this is not an answer. Please make it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.adminCommand(
    {
        setParameter: 1, 
        security.authorization: "enabled" 
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the key thing that was causing the fault/error was noted in Robert Walters response - Use of the TAB in the config file.

Changing this to 4 whitespaces fixed the issue whilst keeping the config file looking neat/readable.

Comment: Please do not use answers as a way to thank other users. Simply restating his answer isn't an answer in and of itself.