# Connect to mongodb URL fails after creating admin user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a web application that connects to MongoDB. Everything works fine before I create the admin user in mongodb:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
```

The URL the API wrote in the `.env` file

- before: `mongodb://localhost:27017/shrimp`
- after: `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/shrimp`

I tied to add a different user, it still doesn't work

- url: mongodb://user:newpassword@localhost:27017/shrimp

The weird thing is, when I use `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/shrimp` in
mongoDB Compass, it can connect, but when I use `mongodb://user:newpassword@localhost:27017/shrimp` it says "Authentication failed."

**EDIT**

The tools I use: [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), Windows 10, [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/).

The `mongodb://user:newpassword@localhost:27017/shrimp` can connect to mongoDB Compass now: `mongodb://user2:1234@localhost:27017/shrimp?authSource=shrimp`
and I try using same code to the dbconnection.js:

```
const URL ="mongodb://user2:1234@localhost:27017/shrimp?authSource=shrimp"
```

**ANSWER**

Short answer: add `?authSource=shrimp`

Long answer:

1. after creating the admin user, check the `mongod.cfg` file. [How to set authorization in mongodb config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325142/how-to-set-authorization-in-mongodb-config-file)
2. login to mongo to check whether it's a success
   `mongo --host localhost --port 27017 -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin`
3. testing the mongo URL format whether it can login in MongoDB Compass
   `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin?authSource=admin`

if can login MongoDB Compass the link should work in JS file

Resulting code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const URL ="mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/admin?authSource=admin"
const connection = {};

async function dbConnect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) return;

  const db = await mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
  console.log(connection.isConnected)
}

module.exports = dbConnect;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What library or driver are you using?
Regardless, you could try adding ?authenticationDatabase=admin to end of the url.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I update the tool I use, and you right add `authSource=shrimp` can log into MongoDB compass, but still, the code in js file did not work.

Comment: sorry, the URL in js file is OK now, I will try my best to edit my content, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add a new database user in your MongoDB account to be able to gain access.

Go to MongoDB and log in to your account.
Choose Database Access under Security.
Click on "Add New Database User".
Create a new user (remember the username & password) and add user.