# Is it possible to have a special character in a string that comes from a YAML file?

Tags: localization, yaml

I'm working on a translation project and I'm moving all of the English strings out of the views and into a YAML file. Some of the very well written strings employ special characters such as ampersands and N-dashes.

Is there any way to include those?

In the meantime I've turned "&" to "and" and "–" to "--"
but, at least in the English version, I feel like the copy starts to loose it's flavor. I doubt the Chinese version will miss these, but maybe they will want different special characters that I don't know about.

Comment: Use singlequotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have special characters in YAML file values as long as they're not at the beginning of a string.

In the case of `&`, for example, if it is the first character of your string, then your YAML parser will think it's [an anchor](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#aliases_and_anchors), when it tries to read the string (if it's not, like `key: this & that`, then it will be read as a string, as you would expect).

For more information about what you can and can't have in your YAML strings (and what are considered special characters), see:

- [YAML Ruby Cookbook](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html)
- The question and accepted answer for [Do I need quotes for strings in Yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

Comment: Thanks! I've been putting special characters as the first character of a string, but maybe I'm getting away with it because every string in my yml file is enclosed in "double quotes." (e.g. twitter_account: "@example")

Comment: @pixelfairy yes, exactly right: if you use [double-quoted strings](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#double-quoted_strings), you'll be able to ensure that none of the characters in your string are interpreted as special characters.