# How to avoid truncating zero leading numbers when inserted with Spring's @Value annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Let's say we have an environment variable exported as:

```
export SOME_STRING_CONFIG_PARAM="01"
```

and `application.properties` with:

```
some.string.config.param=${SOME_STRING_CONFIG_PARAM:01}
```

injected to a Java field:

```
@Value("${some.string.config.param}")
String someStringConfigfParam;
```

After booting the Spring application printing out the field:

```
System.out.println("someStringConfigParam: " + someStringConfigParam);
```

results with:

```
someStringConfigParam: 1
```

How to tell Spring that the value should be treated as a String?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot you're using?

Comment: version 1.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: Is it a `yml` file or `properties`?

Comment: The default `application.properties` file.

Comment: @BorisPavlović I'm unable to reproduce this issue.  Check out my sample project using Spring Boot 1.2.7 https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q37860589  In this sample, the property is not truncated.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka indeed, I have updated the question. There's one more level of delegation with an environment variable and its default value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the correct answer by your demo project:

```
This is the Test Property Value = 01
```

But I get the problem in `yml` file, the reason is `yml` treat `01` as integer by default. Just use double quotes to solve it.

Type examples in `yml` file:

```
a: 123                     # an integer
b: "123"                   # a string, disambiguated by quotes
c: 123.0                   # a float
d: !!float 123             # also a float via explicit data type prefixed by (!!)
e: !!str 123               # a string, disambiguated by explicit type
f: !!str Yes               # a string via explicit type
g: Yes                     # a boolean True (yaml1.1), string "Yes" (yaml1.2)
h: Yes we have No bananas  # a string, "Yes" and "No" disambiguated by context.
```

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML
[Do I need quotes for strings in Yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)