# How do I know when to use double quotes, single quotes, and curly brackets when using with_items in Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have had tasks work for each of these 'with_items' scenarios at one point or another:

```
 with_items: ec2.instances
```

or

```
  with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'
```

or

```
 with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

How do I know when to use the correct one. If I knew, then I wouldn't be running into a trial-and-error situation as much of the time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Ansible < 2.2 (deprecated since 2.1) – bare variables:

```
with_items: ec2.instances
```

Ansible >= 2.2 – templated:

```
with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'
```

From [release notes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/CHANGELOG.md#removed-deprecated):

> **Removed Deprecated:**
>
> - with_ 'bare variable' handling, now loop items must always be templated {{ }} or they will be considered as plain strings.

Single or double quotes doesn't matter in this case.
You can read about differences in quotes from other SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml).