# In yaml file how to convert integer to string

Tags: yaml

How to convert integer to string in yaml. I have seen simply need to put quote . But not working. Still getting value as integer

Comment: Please provide your sample yaml and sample program you are using to read it.

Comment: id: abcd
unit: m
tagData: 1543626000055
tagData1: 3456

Comment: Here tagData1 value need to be string

Comment: Did you try: tagData1: "3456" ? It should work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

Comment: I tried double quotes and single quotes also . Its not working

Comment: Before doing anything else read through the [tour], completely. This question is low quality as several parts are missing to reproduce your issue. You should edit your question (as asked in a comment), to include your YAML input. Do not put such missing information in a comment: **improve your question** instead. How do you check that the scalar is a string or not? (It is working, you are just doing something wrong, or using the wrong software to load the YAML file, but without a complete reproducible discription in your question, we cannot help you).

Comment: I voted to close this question, but will retract my vote when I notice significant enough improvements to the question have been made.