# error parsing stateful.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 35: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: mongodb, deployment, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy mongodb on Kubernetes but I'm getting the error:

> error parsing stateful.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line
>   35: mapping values are not allowed in this context

the line 35 is the container name: - name: **uat-mongo-primary**

I get this error when i try to create the pods but if i comment the lines :

> mongo --eval rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [{ _id: 0,
>   host : "uat-mongo-primary-rc-0:27017" }]});  53             mongo
>   --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({user : \"$MONGO_USER\", pwd  : \"$MONGO_PASSWORD\", roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ]
>   })";

the pods being create normally but i need to initiate the cluster also create an user and password.

this is the full yaml file I'm using, i will appreciate any help:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: uat-mongo-primary
  labels:
    name: uat-mongo-primary
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    name: uat-mongo-primary
  selector:
    name: uat-mongo-primary

---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: uat-mongo-primary-rc
  labels:
    name: uat-mongo-primary-rc
spec:
  serviceName: uat-mongo-primary
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: uat-mongo-primary
        image: mongo
        env:
          - name: "MONGO_DATA_DIR"
            value: "/data/db"
          - name: "MONGO_LOG_DIR"
            value: "/data/logs"
          - name: MONGO_USER
            value: "admin"
          - name: MONGO_PASSWORD
            value: "password"

        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - echo starting;
            ulimit -a;
            mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all;
            mongo --eval rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [{ _id: 0, host : "uat-mongo-primary-rc-0:27017" }]});
            mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({user : \"$MONGO_USER\", pwd  : \"$MONGO_PASSWORD\", roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ] })";
         ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
      volumes:
        - name: uat-mongo-primary-db
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: uat-mongo-primary-pvc
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use YAML strings containing colons (at least with kubectl). You should convert your YAML to JSON (using [this](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv) tool for example) and apply that JSON with kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

To check that your yaml file renders correctly try any YAML to JSON convertor online tool. So it will indicate which fields are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to use double quotes unless you want to force value for "string". There is great explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

Also, what you are doing, it is not best practice, and hard to manage such long complicated commands in yaml files.
I would suggest you to build your own Dockerfile by adding those commands inside Dockerfile and build your own image.

Other option is as you check mongo docker documentation, for initializing new instance

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

So, you can attach PV to this directory, and add your scripts there, then when container will start, it will run your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Alignment for ports in your yml file is incorrect:

`ports:
    - containerPort: 27017`

it must be aligned on same label as image name.