# Add front matter to markdown in Node

Tags: node.js, markdown

I am trying to generate `.md` files by Nodejs, and the file should contain the front matter.

This is what I am doing:

```
let {title,date,markdown_content}=document;
let fileContent = `
---
title: '${title}'
date: ${date}
---
${markdown_content}
`;
```

Now the `title` may contain special characters like `"` `'` and etc(find more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)).

Any nodejs library can be used out of box to do this job? Or I will have to replace the characters manually.