# Do I need quotes for strings containing forward slash / in YAML?

Tags: syntax, yaml, quotes

I have read the answer to this similar question: [Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

However, there was no answer for whether we can escape quotes with strings containing forward slashes `/`.

For example, do we need to add quotes to the following eslint rule `'react/no-deprecated': off`?

Comment: Did you try experimenting - what if you remove them? Parsing fail? Rule doesn't get applied?

Comment: Yes so when I remove the quotes the rule doesn't get applied, but it seems there is no syntax error in YAML

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `/` is not a special character in YAML. YAML allows the escape sequence `\/` in double-quoted scalars to resolve to `/` for JSON compatibility, but there is no requirement to use this escape sequence and no requirement to use quotes at all to use `/` as content character.