# YAML: error parsing a string containing a square bracket as its first character

Tags: ruby, yaml, psychparser

I'm parsing a YAML file in Ruby and some of the input is causing a Psych syntax error:

```
require 'yaml'

example = "my_key: [string] string"
YAML.load(example)
```

Resulting in:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key
          while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1
from [...]/psych.rb:456:in `parse'
```

I received this YAML from an external API that I do not have control over. I can see that editing the input to force parsing as a string, using `my_key: '[string] string'`, as noted in "[Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)", fixes the issue however I don't control  how the input is received.

Is there a way to force the input to be parsed as a string for some keys such as  `my_key`? Is there a workaround to successfully parse this YAML?

Comment: You may want to paste result correctly.

Comment: Just to understand the problem: What do you expect? The string  `[string] string` or the string 'string`? Obviously you don't get valid yaml, so maybe you have a description from the API you use.

Comment: It's weird that an API would return a result in YAML that isn't actually valid YAML :/ But couldn't you just pre-process the response before reading as YAML?

Comment: You may not control how the string is received, but you do have control over it immediately prior to parsing it so munging it isn't out of the question. I'd do it in a small piece of code separate from the parsing code, following all the appropriate cautionary steps of backing up the original until you know your code has successfully parsed it.

Comment: I ran into this scenario with a tool that had a bug choking on parsing `<`, `>` in yaml strings, even when escaped.  It's a bit of a hack, but I ended up using the HTML escaped versions instead successfully (`&lt;`, `&gt;`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to process the response before reading it as YAML. Assuming it's a string, you could use a regex to  replace the problematic pattern with something valid. I.e.

```
resp_str = "---\nmy_key: [string] string\n"
re = /(\: )(\[[a-z]*?\] [a-z]*?)(\n)/
resp_str.gsub!(re, "#{$1}'#{$2}'#{$3}")
#=> "---\n" + "my_key: '[string] string'\n"
```

Then you can do

```
YAML.load(resp_str)
#=> {"my_key"=>"[string] string"}
```

Comment: I've had to do that too many times and agree. It's often the shortest path back to sanity.

Answer (score 4):

It does not work because square brackets have a special meaning in YAML, denoting arrays:

```rb
YAML.load "my_key: [string]"
#⇒ {"my_key"=>["string"]}
```

and `[foo] bar` is an invalid type. One should escape square brackets explicitly

```rb
YAML.load "my_key: \\[string\\] string"
#⇒ {"my_key"=>"\\[string\\] string"}
```

---

Also, one might implement the custom [`Psych` parser](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#module-Psych-label-Mid-level+API).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. However I don't control how this input is being sent as it's being sent from an external API.

Comment: Then the only way to go would be to implement a custom `Psych` parser. [Here](https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2015/04/14/yaml-parser-tuning) is my blof post describing how to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the day I can casually drop my blog post in answer to a question here

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to pre-process an input file to fix known errors prior to passing them to YAML, JSON, or even an XML/HTML parser. It's the nature of the internet that if someone can implement a standard wrong someone will, usually because they had a "bright idea".

Answer (score -1):

There is very native and easy solution. If  you would like to have string context you can always put quotes around it:

```
 YAML.load "my_key: '[string]'"
=> {"my_key"=>"[string]"}
```