# How to escape # in docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, prisma

I have a docker compose file as follows:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
    prisma:
        image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34.10
        restart: always
        ports:
        - '4466:4466'
        environment:
        PRISMA_CONFIG: |
            port: 4466
            databases:
            default:
                connector: mysql
                host: test.mysql.database.azure.com
                database: default@default
                user: rie@dak-prod
                password: ak123#$
                ssl: false
                rawAccess: true
                port: '3306'
                migrations: true
```

When I try the command `docker-compose up -d` the command fails with an error :

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "prisma": "port: 4466
databases:
default:
    connector: mysql
    host: est.mysql.database.azure.com
    database: default@default
    user: rie@dak-prod
    password: ak123#$
    ssl: false
    rawAccess: true
    port: '3306'
    migrations: true
"
```

The reason that I have identified is the `#` in the password. If `#` is not there, it does not throw up this error. How can I escape (use) hash the the docker compose file?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is not with a `#` but with a `$` symbol.

You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a `$$` allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.

So in your case `ak123#$` must be written as `ak123#$$`

[Reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

Answer (score 1):

Quote your string to include [special characters in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/596285) like the `#`, and escape the dollar sign using a second dollar sign to [prevent docker-compose from expanding it](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution):

```
password: "ak123#$$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use is base64 encode function. convert your password into base64 and try. should work.

Like this

```
echo "ak123#$" | base64
```

and whatever the output use as your password and more secure way

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` have two issues:

- `$` should be escaped with `$$` as pointed by [@Suhail Gupta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63467795/5465973) and [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution):

> You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign

- `PRISMA_CONFIG` indentation under `environment:` is invalid, as `PRISMA_CONFIG` should be a subelement of `environment`

You should use something like:

```
    environment:
      # proper indentation to have PRISMA_CONFIG part of environment
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
          port: 4466
          databases:
          default:
              connector: mysql
              host: test.mysql.database.azure.com
              database: default@default
              user: rie@dak-prod
              # double $ to have a literal '$'
              password: ak123#$$
              ssl: false
              rawAccess: true
              port: '3306'
              migrations: true
```