# yaml config not allowed some characters - invalid tag

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Yaml file not allowed password starting from !  example value as here !abc1234
any idea how to put that as a value in yaml config file

```
   org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: Can't construct a java object for !abc1234; exception=Invalid tag: !abc1234 in 'reader', line 82,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/8230378) regarding YAML and quotes.

This states that you have to

> Use quotes if your value includes special characters, (e.g. `:`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `,`, `&`, `*`, `#`, `?`, `|`, `-`, `<`, `>`, `=`, `!`, `%`, `@`, `\`).