# R replace quoted values in YAML

Tags: r, yaml

I am replacing values in Yaml files, and need to choose which values will be quoted.

I don't understand the current behaviour of `write.yaml`

```
library(yaml)
test <- list("a"=list("b"="123", "c"="rabbitmq"))
as.yaml(test)
write_yaml(test, "test.yaml")
```

In `test.yaml`, `"123"` is quoted while `rabbitmq` is not. How can I deliberately choose what will be quoted ?

Comment: for the record, the yaml package as-is produces valid results even without quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### workaround

Although this might be difficult for more complex YAML file outputs, there is a workaround to the apparent inability of the yaml package to force quotations, as explored below. We can use regex to match, in this example, any non-quoted continuous group of letters or numbers and force quotations around it.

```r
library(stringr)

test <- list("a"=list("b"=123L, "c"="rabbitmq", d = "Yes"))
test_yaml <- as.yaml(test)
test_yaml
#> [1] "a:\n  b: 123\n  c: rabbitmq\n  d: 'Yes'\n"
```

We can see here that we might want to quote `123` and `rabbitmq` (`Yes` is already in quotes).

```r
test_yaml <- str_replace_all(test_yaml, "(?<=:\\s)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)(?=\n)", "'\\1'")
test_yaml
#> [1] "a:\n  b: '123'\n  c: 'rabbitmq'\n  d: 'Yes'\n"
```

And then write this to your YAML file.

```r
write_yaml(test_yaml, "/Users/caldwellst/Desktop/test.yaml")
```

We then get your, I'm assuming, desired output.

```yaml
  a:
    b: '123'
    c: 'rabbitmq'
    d: 'Yes'
```

#### yaml package

`write_yaml` is using strings to force a quote, because otherwise `123` would be interpreted as numeric. You don't need quotes for `rabbitmq` because it will automatically be interpreted as a string. If you actually want `123` to be interpreted as numeric, just pass it as such.

```r
test <- list("a"=list("b"=123, "c"="rabbitmq"))
as.yaml(test)
write_yaml(test, "test.yaml")
```

Then you get:

```yaml
a:
  b: 123.0 # pass b as 123L to force integer output
  c: rabbitmq
```

Per the documentation of `write_yaml`:

> Character vectors that have a class of ‘verbatim’ will not be quoted in the output YAML document except when the YAML specification requires it

Although that is a way to force certain values to be output without quotes, there appears to be no easy way to force quoting of values. I've tried with passing `unicode = T` and explicit quotes in the string, but they are removed. As well, I tried to trick the system by passing in various handlers to manipulate class (and remove `verbatim` if it was there. However, none seem to work. As the source code is in C, not able to get something working with the `write_yaml` function.

There's a detailed answer about the YAML syntax and quoting in general in this [great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml).

Comment: I want to have quotes **anyway**. I don't want to take the risk.

Comment: Then you're not really following YAML standards, so you'd need to produce a workaround since the `yaml` library is designed around those (obviously). Not sure exactly how you'd do it but maybe someone else will.

Comment: well I have very valid YAML files with quotes, so I am indeed following a valid yaml specification, only they are arbitrary.

Comment: Fair point, just not sure the `write_yaml` library will enforce quotes except where necessary. Maybe look into the source code for cases like when `"Yes"` or numerics are passed as values.

Comment: Aha! I think there might be a way based on the documentation actually.

Comment: can't wait ;)...

Comment: Sorry, can't figure it out.

Comment: You can see the workaround I have given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241275/discussion-between-caldwellst-and-gaut).

Comment: could you please add in your answer how to specify only the value `c` in `str_replace_all`? That would work for me i think

Comment: I guess I could now build a function which quotes values in the converted yaml object before writing. will check...

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to generate characters that are quoted very straightforwardly without any esoteric workaround.

So from the help to `yaml::as.yaml` we have:

"Character vectors that have an attribute of ‘quoted’ will be wrapped in double quotes (see below for example)."

Now, here is the test:

```
veck1 <- c("a")
veck2 <- veck1
attr(veck2, which = "quoted") <- TRUE # actually any attribute value works here
test_list <- list(unquoted_char = veck1, quoted_char = veck2)
write_yaml(test_list, "./test.yaml")
```

gives me the yaml file:

```
unquoted_char: a
quoted_char: "a"
```

which is exactly what was asked for @gaut.

Maybe the R/package version need an update, here are my settings.

R version:
major          4
minor          2.1
year           2022
month          06
day            23
svn rev        82513
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid

package version `yaml: ‘2.3.5’`