# The meaning of the quotation marks in "image"-keyword entries in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file can accept the keyword: [image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#image), "to specify a Docker image that the job runs in."

I have encountered that the input entries of this keyword are sometimes enclosed with [quotation marks (" ")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark).

For example:

```
image: alpine
```

vs

```
image: "alpine"
```

GitLab Docs also contains both instances (sort of): [quoted entry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#imagename) vs [unquoted entry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#imageentrypoint).

Could you please tell me whether there is any meaning of these quotation marks? If so, what is its meaning, and when should we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation marks are only significant with respect to YAML syntax and nothing else. GitLab always reads YAML according to the YAML specification. In the case you mention, `alpine` and `"alpine"` are parsed identically, there is no functional difference.

See also: [YAML: Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

In some cases, you need quotes to avoid YAML interpreting your strings as other kinds of YAML types. For instance: `key: 123` is not the same as `key: "123"` for example.

As another example, if your string happens to start with a `*` you will need quotes to avoid it being interpreted as a [YAML anchor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts):

```yaml
# good:
artifacts:
  paths:
    - "*package.json"

# bad
artifacts:
  paths:
    - *package.json
```