# How to solve this error about jekyll serve?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, serve

ERROR in command prompt

PS G:\github\blog\maloveforme.github.io> bundle exec jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: G:/github/blog/maloveforme.github.io/_config.yml
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
Source: G:/github/blog/maloveforme.github.io
Destination: G:/github/blog/maloveforme.github.io/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating...
Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for 2022:Integer string.gsub(replaceable_char, "-") ^^^^^ in G:/github/blog/maloveforme.github.io/_layouts/single.html C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:364:in` replace_character_sequence_with_hyphen': undefined method `gsub' for 2022:Integer (NoMethodError)

```
  string.gsub(replaceable_char, "-")
        ^^^^^
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:215:in `slugify'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/filters.rb:63:in `slugify'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/strainer.rb:56:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:86:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/variable.rb:84:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/variable.rb:82:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/variable.rb:82:in `inject'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/variable.rb:82:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:80:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in render_segment'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb:158:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb:158:in `block in render_segment'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:123:in `stack'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb:150:in `render_segment'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb:79:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:82:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:44:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:44:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:123:in `stack'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:43:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:82:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:208:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:242:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:207:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:220:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:59:in `measure_counts'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:63:in `measure_bytes'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:37:in `block in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:70:in `measure_time'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:36:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/inclusion.rb:16:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:208:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:123:in `stack'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:206:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:91:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:44:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:44:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:123:in `stack'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:43:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:82:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:208:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:242:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:207:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:220:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:59:in `measure_counts'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:63:in `measure_bytes'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:37:in `block in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:70:in `measure_time'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:36:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/inclusion.rb:16:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:208:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:123:in `stack'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:206:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:103:in `render_node_to_output'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:91:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:208:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:242:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:207:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:220:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:59:in `measure_counts'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:63:in `measure_bytes'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:37:in `block in render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:70:in `measure_time'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:36:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:131:in `render_liquid'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:194:in `render_layout'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:163:in `place_in_layouts'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:93:in `render_document'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:63:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:547:in `render_regenerated'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:532:in `block (2 levels) in render_docs'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:531:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:531:in `block in render_docs'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:530:in `each_value'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:530:in `render_docs'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:210:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:80:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error is telling you that you defined Integer literal `2022` somewhere instead of `'2022'` and it can't convert it to a slug.

Comment: @AdamZapaśnik where is a slug?

Comment: @malove although the object is called `string` it is in fact an integer, and can't be converted automatically to a string (`#gsub` works on strings only)

Answer (score 3):

I see in your repo you have a tag `2022`

```yaml
tags:
  - 2022
```

In yml you have to write '2022' to treat it as a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/6150184

> Use quotes to force a string, e.g. if your key or value is `10` but you want it to return a String and not a Fixnum, write `'10'` or `"10"`.

So in your case update tags:

```yaml
tags:
  - '2022'
```

Comment: very very very thanks !! 
I was at a loss for 2 hours, but thanks to you, I solved it.