# When using Apigee Edge, and OpenApi versions 3.* when are quotes needed around nodes in the specs specifically?

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

I am getting errors in Apigee when I try to reference a spec while trying to add a product to the portal.  I have seen openApi/Swagger examples where nodes are sometimes wrapped in double-quotes, some in single-quotes, and some with no quotes.  I get a message that the yaml/Json is not valid.

Is there a document where it explains when openAPI wants quotes and where it doesn't.  I do not like to put in pointless quotes around things.

I am using openAPI version 3.0.3. in Apigee Edge

I've used different OpenAPI spec editors.  The Specs editor in Apigee doesn't react to things I feel are incorrect.  The Try-Me functionality works.  Other editors will highlight different lines.   I correct them, then paste them back into the Apigee Specs editor.  But then when trying to add the Product to the Portal using a Spec, it tells me that the YAML/JSON is invalid.

I am not sure this is important but this a spec I have written after the proxy was written.  I don't know if maybe this is an association issue.  Later I'll have another question on how to relate a spec to an existing proxy.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your OpenAPI file, but see if this answer your question - [Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109912/113116) Consider also contacting Apigee support - maybe your file is valid and the problem is actually on their side.

Comment: @Helen, Thank you for the link.  Excellent.  With over 963 upvotes, I'm going with that.  I am going to do a line by line excercise to see if I can isolate the offending line.  I'll be back with those results.  I prefer having the least amount of visual noise in openApi specs.

Comment: Plus, @Helen, I'll be posting a ticket with Apigee.  I'm pretty sure I have everything correct.  But need their eyes now to show me where the problem is.

Comment: I determined that a date field in an example was coded as 'MM\/dd\/yyyy".   I also discovered when using double-quotes the escape character "\" is recognized.   I removed the back-slashes and it worked.

Comment: Additionally, I learned that quotes around the responses codes (i.e. '200','201') are not necessary.  200, 201, etc. works just fine too.