# Load element as string when it ends with a colon

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML document where some values end with a colon, something like:

```yaml
foo:
  - bar
  - baz::
```

When I load the document with `yaml.load`, the `baz::` element gets converted to a dictionary `{'baz:' : ''}`. However, I would like to read it as string.

I've tried loading the file with the `yaml.BaseLoader`, however this did not help. Is there a way to specify that the elements should not be converted to a dict?

Comment: The `BaseLoader` only changes what happens with the scalars, i.e. makes them all into strings (and not booleans, float, date, sexagesimal, etc when matching an appropriate pattern). The YAML syntax stays the same and a colon followed by whitespace (or EOF) following a plain scalar is always a value indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: "*Is there a way to specify that the elements should not be converted to a dict?*"**

Just quote them.

Whereby for

```yaml
foo:
  - bar
  - baz::
```

an output result will become

```yaml
foo:
  - bar
  - 'baz:': null
```

for

```yaml
bar:
  - foo
  - "foz::"
```

it will stay with

```yaml
bar:
  - foo
  - 'foz::'
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [YAML: Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235064/6771046)

Comment: I really like your use of the word "stay", when it actually changes ;-)

Comment: @Anthon, The reason why I've used the word stay is, the expected behavior was the value should not change, not become a dictionary but stay as a string, the character `:` should not become interpreted. So quoting will leave the value as is.