# SaltStack cmd.run with curl and json body

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a trivial task that I am stuck to write salt state for. I need to call REST endpoint using curl with json body. This is

`curl localhost/endpoint -d '{"some" : "data"}'`

My idea was to simply take this and put it into salt state by using `cmd.run`. Does not work. So far I have this:

```
{%- set data = {'some': 'data'} %}

Use echo instead of curl:
  cmd.run:
    - name:  echo '{{ data|json }}'
```

And this gives me

```
failed: Unknown yaml render error; line 5

Use echo instead of curl:
  cmd.run:
    - name:  echo '{"some": "data"}'    <======================
```

I have Salt version 2014.7.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the problem was the ":" within the `curl` command that was interpreted as YAML (see: [How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml))

I ended up using the [multi-line approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22483116/101434). That allows me to write the command with no escaping while variables (e.g pillar data) are still interpreted correctly.

E.g.

```
Salt state description:
  cmd.run:
    - name: >-
        curl -X GET  "https://api.example.com/client/{{ pillar['client_id'] }}" -H  "X-Auth-Email: name@example.co.za" -H "X-Auth-Key: {{ pillar['api_key'] }}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"some_json":true}'
```

Comment: You've saved a lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

When working with json it is sometimes easier to avoid the jinja renderer altogether. The following example uses the [pybojects](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.pyobjects.html) renderer (which is nice for a lot of other reasons too).

echo.sls:

```
#!pyobjects
import json

data = {'some': 'data'}

def dump(d):
   return "'" + json.dumps(d).replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"

Cmd.run("echo {}".format(dump(data)))
```

Note that the custom `dump` function definition and usage is added for the sake of completeness.