# How to you escape special character from bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a `yml` bitbucket pipeline where I would like to auto commit a message containing `#` and `:`

I am doing :

`- git commit -m "[skip ci] $ISSUE #comment Link : $LINK"`

The issue is the pipeline don't run cause it consider `#` to be a comment.

I tried to escape it using

```
 - git commit -m |-
    "[skip ci] $ISSUE #comment Link : $LINK"
```

or

```
 - git commit -m |-
    "[skip ci] $ISSUE '#'comment Link ':' $LINK"
```

but they dont work as expected

I am expecting a commit message like
`"[skip ci] UI-12 #comment Link : www.test.com/123"`

What I get is either

```
bash: opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/bashScript17301903987873752811.sh: line 23: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
```

or the `'` remaining

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What did you expect? `"[skip ci] UI-12 #comment Link : www.test.com/123"` looks correct...

Comment: sorry my text was confusing. This is what I expect but I dont get this.

Comment: Have you tried `\#`?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if, as described in [Advanced techniques for writing pipes](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/advanced-techniques-for-writing-pipes/), strong quoting would be enough:

```
 - git commit -m |-
       '[skip ci] $ISSUE #comment Link :'" $LINK"
      ^^^                              ^^^
```

If not, as commented:

```
 - git commit -m |-
       "[skip ci] $ISSUE \#comment Link : $LINK"
                         ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two sets of quoting to deal with here:

- YAML quoting, which you've sort-of addressed, and
- shell quoting, which you've also sort-of addressed.

Without actually trying it (as I don't have any Bitbucket setup of my own), I believe that this suffices:

```yaml
      - step:
        script:
          - |-
            git commit -m "[skip ci] $ISSUE #comment Link : $LINK"
```

Note that there are some issues with yaml 1.1 vs 1.2; see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991517/how-to-escape-colons-and-other-special-characters-in-a-yaml-string#comment64842639_33000792) on [How to escape colons and other special characters in a YAML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991517/1256452)