# yaml Error while parsing. Expected <block end>, but found <scalar>

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, yaml, swagger

I'm trying to test a swagger api with got-swag (npm package)

When I try to validate the json response with a json schema I get a parseError when the seperate yaml files get combined into one yaml and json file. The origin is the -validate() line. The validate() originates from the got-swag package but it fails in it's underlying **jsonschema.validate( data, schema );** dependency

```
 x-tests:
        - description: Should return array of ferries
          steps:
            - get('/api/get/link/ferries')
            - equal(res.statusCode, 200)
            - ok(res.json.length > 0)
            - validate(res.json,  $ref: '#/definitions/ferry')
```

This is the resulting error:

```
           throw new exports.ParserError('while parsing a block mapping', this.marks.slice(-1)[0], "expected <block end>, but found " + token.id, token.start_mark);
        ^
while parsing a block mapping
  on line 29, column 15
expected <block end>, but found <scalar>
  on line 29, column 76
    at ParserError.YAMLError [as constructor] (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\errors.js:70:46)
    at ParserError.MarkedYAMLError [as constructor] (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\errors.js:90:45)
    at new ParserError (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\parser.js:17:48)
    at Loader.__dirname.Parser.Parser.parse_block_mapping_key (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\parser.js:433:15)
    at Loader.__dirname.Parser.Parser.check_event (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\parser.js:61:48)
    at Loader.__dirname.Composer.Composer.compose_mapping_node (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\composer.js:248:20)
    at Loader.__dirname.Composer.Composer.compose_node (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\composer.js:160:21)
    at Loader.__dirname.Composer.Composer.compose_sequence_node (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\composer.js:216:30)
    at Loader.__dirname.Composer.Composer.compose_node (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\composer.js:158:21)
    at Loader.__dirname.Composer.Composer.compose_mapping_node (C:\Users\dvbets\Documents\Workspace\Repos\node_modules\yaml-js\lib\composer.js:250:27)
```

Answer (score 5):

That line needs to be wrapped in quotes in order to escape the inner `:` character:

```
- "validate(res.json,  $ref: '#/definitions/ferry')"
                           ^
```

`:` is a special character in YAML, a separator for `key: value` pairs. Without escaping, that line is parsed as the key name `validate(res.json,  $ref` with the value `'#/definitions/ferry')` and the parser chokes on `)` after the ending quotation mark.

Related: [How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301650/113116)