# add youtube video .yaml file

Tags: youtube, yaml

I've a .yaml file that inside there is a code that allow to load a .mp4 video.

```
html: "<video autoplay preload=\"none\" muted loop>\n  <source src=\"/wp-
content/img/646440130.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>"
```

I'd like to replace it with a YouTube code video.

for example with this :

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dT2owtxkU8k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i try like this :

```
html: "<iframe width=\"1920\" height=\"1080\" 
src=\"/https://www.youtube.com/embed/dT2owtxkU8k\" frameborder=\"0\" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

Anyone know the code to add it with right syntax ?

thanks

Comment: Look in youtube. the code is there in the "share" section

Comment: yes, of course. But it's a yaml file and I can't just copy and paste the code, because I get a syntax error. I need an help with code.

Comment: Escape it like you did with your exemple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml

Comment: I updated the code with an example of source code of Youtube video. For Privacy I don't post the original video.

Comment: You did it it in your first exemple. Just quote the code and escape all the existing quotes with a \ . Just like in your first exemple...

Comment: I've updated the code, but not works.. it looks right?

Comment: Why is there a / in front of the `https`?