# Script command using ":" causing error in .gitlab-ci.yml execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Below my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
image: docker:latest

services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - deploy_dev_env

Deploy DEV Environment:

    stage: deploy_dev_env

    script:

        - curl -v -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X PUT -F uploadInput=@schema/schema.xml -F overwrite=true -F xmlaEnabledFlag=true -F parameters="DataSource=outputDS" -F parameters="EnableXmla=true" -u $PENTAHO_DEPLOY_USER:$PENTAHO_DEPLOY_PASSWORD http://$PENTAHO_HOST/pentaho/plugin/data-access/api/datasource/analysis/catalog/sca
```

This very simple script is causing an error because the colons(:) in the `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` piece.

Running the CI Lint in the script I get the following:

```
Status: syntax is incorrect

jobs:deploy dev environment:script config should be a string or an array containing strings and arrays of strings
```

If I replace `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` by `"Content-Type multipart/form-data"` (removed the ":"), I get I correct syntax for my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Is this a bug or should I re-write my curl command in a different way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) warn about special characters in yaml script:

> Note: Sometimes, script commands will need to be wrapped in single or double quotes. For example, commands that contain a colon (:) need to be wrapped in quotes so that the YAML parser knows to interpret the whole thing as a string rather than a “key: value” pair. Be careful when using special characters: :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `.

One of the option would be to use [yaml block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/)

```yaml
Deploy DEV Environment:
    stage: deploy_dev_env
    script: >
        curl -v -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X PUT -F uploadInput=@schema/schema.xml -F overwrite=true -F xmlaEnabledFlag=true -F parameters="DataSource=outputDS" -F parameters="EnableXmla=true" -u $PENTAHO_DEPLOY_USER:$PENTAHO_DEPLOY_PASSWORD http://$PENTAHO_HOST/pentaho/plugin/data-access/api/datasource/analysis/catalog/sca
```

or use some other way to [escape colon in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml).

Comment: Based on your answer and link for the docs, I've used single quotes to wrap the command. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue due to yaml syntax before and the workaround i found was

Store the "Content-Type: application/json" as an environment variable in the CICD settings
for example

```
Key: HEADER
Value: Content-Type: application/json
```

and in your script

```
- curl -v -H "$HEADER" -X PUT -F uploadInput=@schema/schema.xml -F overwrite=true -F xmlaEnabledFlag=true -F parameters="DataSource=outputDS" -F parameters="EnableXmla=true" -u $PENTAHO_DEPLOY_USER:$PENTAHO_DEPLOY_PASSWORD http://$PENTAHO_HOST/pentaho/plugin/data-access/api/datasource/analysis/catalog/sca
```

Comment: It's an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After going through several options, I found below simple solution
Use like this,

```
Content_Type="Content-Type:"
export RESULT="$(echo "$Content_Type" multipart/form-data)"
echo "Result is " $RESULT
```

Use $RESULT as variable there