# Add style to elements in HTML tags in YAML file

Tags: yaml

My requirement is to create tooltip inside a YAML file which will be linked to their respective fields in a react-form. Each property will have a tooltip that will be in HTML format as we might need to have anchor tags in some cases. My file content is as below:

```
application:
  form1:
   employee:    
     firstName:
       content: <a href="https://google.com">This is legal first name</a>
     lastName: 
       content: <p>This is legal last name</p>
```

Now problem over here is that I might need to add style to some tags in some cases like:

```
application:
  form1:
   employee:    
     firstName:
       content: <a href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline">This is legal first name</a>
     lastName: 
       content: <p>This is legal last name</p>
```

How can  do so in YAML file as colon in style gives format error and in case I need to repeat styles, then how can I refer class over here? I am new to this concept, so any guidance and help would be greatly appreciated.

Can anyone please tell if I am writing in correct manner or is there some other way to write HTML in YAML file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml)