# Multi-line bash script in yaml for EC2 Image Builder

Tags: amazon-ec2, yaml

I'm trying to create a custom component document. While I've tested the yaml file using various yaml linters, EC2 Image builder is complaining with the below error

```
Failed to create component. Fix the error(s) and try again:
The value supplied for parameter 'data' is not valid. Parsing step 'ConfigureMySQL' in phase 'build' failed. Error: line 4: cannot unmarshal map into string.
```

And I'm unable to figure out what is wrong with my yaml file

```
name: MyJavaAppTestDocument
description: This is JavaApp Document
schemaVersion: 1.0

phases:
  - name: build
    steps:
      - name: InstallSoftware
        action: ExecuteBash
        inputs:
          commands:
            - sudo yum update -y
            - sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0
            - sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y tomcat8.5
            - sudo yum install -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
            - sudo yum install -y mysql-community-server
      
      - name: ConfigureTomcat
        action: ExecuteBash
        inputs:
          commands:
            - sudo sed -i 's/<\/tomcat-users>/\n<role rolename="manager-gui"\/>\n  <role 
              rolename="manager-script"\/>\n  <role rolename="admin-gui"\/>\n  <user username="admin" 
              password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,admin-gui"\/>\n<\/tomcat-users>/' 
              /etc/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml
            - sudo systemctl start tomcat
            - sudo systemctl enable tomcat
      
      - name: ConfigureMySQL
        action: ExecuteBash
        inputs:
          commands:
            - sudo systemctl start mysqld
            - sudo systemctl enable mysqld
            - mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //')
            - mysql -u root -p$mysqlpass --connect-expired-password -h localhost -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'whyDoTh1s@2020'"
            - |
              sudo cat <<EoF > /tmp/mysql-create-user.sql
              CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'whyDoTh1s@2020';
              GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
              EoF

            - sudo mysql -u root -pwhyDoTh1s@2020 -h localhost < /tmp/mysql-create-user.sql
```

Appreciate if someone could help me find the error. The objective is to build an AMI with pre-configured software and settings.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? @Aashish Jolly

Answer (score 2):

Although @micah-l-c answer can help in OP's case.

I would suggest an alternate approach which can also help and can be more correct solution towards this problem.

Erroneous line here is

```
- mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //')
```

This can be rewritten as

```
- |-
    mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //')
```

OR

```
- >-
    mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //')
```

Now `:` will be escaped fine with above approach.

I faced a similar issue and I will give an example where @micah-l-c solution didn't work and above approach worked fine.

Below was line i was adding in the ec2 image builder component

```
- echo "user1    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

I put single quotes around `:` and it made /etc/sudoers malformed and thus it didn't work.

I replace above line like this

```
- |-
    echo "user1    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

References :

[How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml)

Comment: This is a better, more general answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because of the `:` in this line:

```
- mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //')
```

The YAML parser is interpreting that line as creating a map instead of creating a string entry in an existing map. A workaround I was able to use in my own YAML was to surround the `:` with single quotes, so the problem line would become

```
- mysqlpass=$(sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/.*root@localhost':' //')
```

According to my own use and [this online YAML parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) I tested with that solution applied, that should do the trick.