# Ignore specify slash character in yaml config for spring boot admin application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I want to configure the service label `app.kubernetes.io/part-of: myapp` for the kubernetes discovery in my spring boot admin application.

`app.kubernetes.io/part-of` is a [recommended label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/), so I think there should be a way to configure it for the service discovery.

```
spring:
    cloud:
        kubernetes:
            discovery:
                namespace: myspace
                all-namespaces: true
                service-labels:
                    'app.kubernetes.io/part-of': myapp
```

Unfortunately all special characters are removed in the yaml keys, which I notice in the `configprops` actuator.

**My questions:**

- How can I specify a slash in a yaml key for spring boot?
- Is there an alternative solution to specify my service label?

**Hints:**

- Other [general yaml questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml), which suggest to escape or quote the characters, does not help here. Or I missed something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can encode it with square brackets

```
"[app.kubernetes.io/part-of]": myapp
```