# Adding og images to VitePress

Tags: yaml-front-matter, vitepress

I've seen that in the VitePress `.md` files you can add meta description and keywords like this,

```
head:
  - - meta
    - name: description
      content: my custom description
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to add `og:title` or `og:image`, it seems that the `:` throws an error when compiling.

Answer (score 2):

Refer:

- [YAML: Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109912/11613622)
- [How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301650/11613622)

---

So you basically need to do:

```yaml
head:
  - - meta
    - name: 'og:title'
      content: Foo Bar
```

---

Moreover, VitePress supports setting the frontmatter in JSON too. So this should also work:

```json
{ "head": [["meta", { "name": "og:title", "content": "Foo Bar" }]] }
```